# Cannot use xdebug on CLI , using docker

Tags: php, docker, xdebug

I can use xdebug on a the web app, but when I try to execute a Symfony command, the execution doesn't stop at  breakpoints.

This is my `dockerfile`:

```
FROM phpdockerio/php74-fpm:latest
WORKDIR "/application"

# Fix debconf warnings upon build
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive


# Install selected extensions and other stuff

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install php7.4-gd php7.4-memcached php7.4-mysql php7.4-redis php7.4-xdebug \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install  libfontconfig1 libxrender1 libxext6  \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*
```

this is my `docker-compose`

```
version: "3.1"
services:

    memcached:
      image: memcached:alpine
      container_name: my-memcached

    mailhog:
      image: mailhog/mailhog:latest
      container_name: my-mailhog
      ports:
        - "1026:8025"

    redis:
      image: redis:alpine
      container_name: my-redis

    mariadb:
      image: mariadb:10.4
      container_name: my-mariadb
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
        - .:/application
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb
        - MYSQL_USER=mypass
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
      ports:
        - "1028:3306"

    webserver:
      image: nginx:alpine
      container_name: my-webserver
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
          - .:/application
          - ./phpdocker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      ports:
       - "80:80"

    php-fpm:
      build: phpdocker/php-fpm
      container_name: my-php-fpm
      working_dir: /application
      environment:
        PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=myServer"
      volumes:
        - .:/application
        - ./phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
      extra_hosts:
        - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

this is my `php-ini-overrides`

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 108M

[Xdebug]
;zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20210902/xdebug.so"

xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.discover_client_host=0
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
```

NO problem with web applications , but is not possible to debug cli apps, I added tried to add some variables to all files but never worked, Do I missed something?

Comment: 1) Make sure that Xdebug is enabled in CLI -- just `php -v` and it will show that there. 2) If it is there, write some simple PHP script and call `xdebug_info();` there and share the output; 3) Make sure you have enabled Xdebug logging -- it will tell if it tries to connect to somewhere and what the possible response is etc.

Comment: I'm asking this... because I see `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini` path in your `docker-compose`. The **/fpm/** part clearly suggests that this will be applied to your web server and NOT CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment the `zend_extension` and fill the proper path to .so file.

The global $_SERVER variable is not populated by CLI SAPI and then client discovering does not work.

Comment: I tried but didn't work, I checked `/usr/lib/php/20190902/` folder inside the container and xdebug.so is there

Comment: Try to launch the php with the following command line options https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-a-php-cli-script.html#start-the-script-with-debugging-using-php-command-line-switches

Comment: I have to execute a symfony command not sure if this way works

Comment: symfony command is php-script too. Use php -d... bin/console command

Comment: I tried using the container ip as `-dxdebug.client_host` and 127.0.0.1 too , but didn't work

Comment: The address of your host machine inside php container is host.docker.internal

Comment: I think that `host.docker.internal` is for windows I'm using ubuntu, and I get the container ip with a comamnd

Comment: What is xdebug client you use and where it was installed ?

Comment: xdebug.so is on `/usr/lib/php/20190902/` folder and I tried `phpstorm` and `vscode`

Comment: IDEs phpstorm and vscode are xdebug clients that are listening 9003 port on your host machine. Hence client_host must be an address of the host machine. Inside the php-container, the 127.0.0.1 address is the address of the container itself

Comment: with 127.0.0.1 doen't work too